# Upgrade from Apache 2.8.3 to 2.12.2 causes JSON stripping

Tags: apache-camel

Upgrading Camel from 2.8.3 to 2.12.2 has stripped away the custom JSON text that we are using.  What originally was created in 2.8.3 is this:
{"@command":"java class","memberId":9}

What then is created is this:
{"memberId":9}

Looking at the Camel examples online it looks like the latter is the correct way.  Unfortunately, the code I'm using at work expects the first version.  Is there a way that I can make it back to the previous version.  This only occurs when I upgrade Camel.  If I leave it at 2.8.3, the original version works.  Camel needs to be upgraded though to use RAW to use a password correctly, and that was only introduced in Camel 2.11. I'm using Java with Camel to pass messages.

I can post code if needed.  I feel like I'm missing something that needs to be added to the code.

```
package com.sesamecom.messaging.event;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonTypeInfo;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;

/**
 * Base class for commands that can be marshaled to and from JSON strings.
 */
@JsonSerialize
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,    property="@command")
public abstract class MarshaledEvent {
}

package com.sesamecom.messaging.event.feature;

/**
 *
 */
final public class ReactivationFeatureStatusChanged extends MemberFeatureStatusChanged {
@SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration", "deprecation"})
@Deprecated // required for json serialization
public ReactivationFeatureStatusChanged() {
}

public ReactivationFeatureStatusChanged(Integer memberId, Boolean enabled) {
    super(memberId, enabled);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ReactivationFeatureStatusChanged{" +
            "memberId=" + getMemberId() +
            ", enabled=" + isEnabled() +
            '}';
    }
}



package com.sesamecom.messaging.dispatch;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import com.sesamecom.messaging.event.MarshaledEvent;
import com.sesamecom.messaging.event.ingest.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class IngestEventTransformer implements MessageTransformer {
private static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\{\"@command\":\"(com\\.sesamecom\\.messaging\\.event\\.(fact|ingest)\\.\\w+)\",\"");

private static ImmutableMap<String, Class<? extends MarshaledEvent>> eventMap =
    ImmutableMap.<String, Class<? extends MarshaledEvent>>builder()
            .put("com.sesamecom.messaging.event.ingest.AccountIngested", VisitorAccountIngested.class)
            .put("com.sesamecom.messaging.event.ingest.AddressIngested", VisitorAddressIngested.class)
            .put("com.sesamecom.messaging.event.ingest.AppointmentIngested", VisitorAppointmentIngested.class)
            .put("com.sesamecom.messaging.event.ingest.EmailIngested", VisitorEmailIngested.class)
            .put("com.sesamecom.messaging.event.ingest.LedgerIngested", VisitorLedgerIngested.class)
            .put("com.sesamecom.messaging.event.ingest.PhoneIngested", VisitorPhoneIngested.class)
            .put("com.sesamecom.messaging.event.ingest.RecallIngested", VisitorRecallIngested.class)

            .put("com.sesamecom.messaging.event.ingest.ReinitialUploadIngestCompleted", ReinitialIngested.class)
            .put("com.sesamecom.messaging.event.ingest.InitialUploadIngestCompleted", ReinitialIngested.class)
            .put("com.sesamecom.messaging.event.ingest.VisitorTemporalDataIngestEvent", VisitorTemporalDataIngested.class)
            .put("com.sesamecom.messaging.event.ingest.VisitorIngestEvent", VisitorIngested.class)
            .put("com.sesamecom.messaging.event.ingest.AccountIngestEvent", VisitorAccountIngested.class)
            .put("com.sesamecom.messaging.event.ingest.AppointmentIngestEvent", VisitorAppointmentIngested.class)
            .put("com.sesamecom.messaging.event.ingest.LedgerIngestEvent", VisitorLedgerIngested.class)
            .put("com.sesamecom.messaging.event.ingest.MemberReferrerIngestEvent", MemberReferrerIngested.class)
            .put("com.sesamecom.messaging.event.ingest.RecallIngestEvent", VisitorRecallIngested.class)
            .put("com.sesamecom.messaging.event.ingest.ReferrerIngestEvent", ReferrerIngested.class)
            .put("com.sesamecom.messaging.event.fact.PatientResponsibilityChanged", PatientResponsibilityIngested.class)
    .build();

@Override
public String transform(String message) throws IOException {
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(message);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String command = matcher.group(1);
        if (eventMap.containsKey(command))
            message = message.replace(command, eventMap.get(command).getCanonicalName());
    }

    return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: please post some code and from where @command comes from ? Some context would be helpful here !

Comment: The code above is not using Camel. Maybe its the upgrade of jackson. You can try using the same version of jackson as before.

Comment: Claus, that was the solution!  Thank you very much.  :)